# SSD-dual booting with two hard disks

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, grub-efi

The goal here is, how best to have windows on an SSD, Ubuntu on the HDD and the ability to boot both at will.

I have attempted the dual boot thing previously and then windows 10 decided to demolish everything ubuntu with a big update. This time I am more much more prepared!
[image: partition-setup]
Firstly I have a backup of every single MB, I have cloned the window "C" drive and optimised for SSD migration. I have put all data in a large partition. I have moved everything around (See screenshot) as such that all ubuntu related partitions are FIRST(left to right) as I read it makes it faster, I used easeus pro version on win10 for all these steps.
Ubuntu partitions are --> "/",swap,"/home" and "/boot". I was scared to delete the initial 260 boot partition so I created a new one at 550MB. I didn't want to break the system. To be honest I am unsure where is the system booting up from But they are both there.

I will place an SSD where an HDD drive is. The HDD will go in the cd drive via a HDD caddy (goes where the cd drive is or currently is). My question is what is the correct way to NOT break the system?
I will clone the the windows "c" on to the SSD, remove the boot partitions and original "C" partition from the HDD. Will this work or will it break?
Will I need to do anything more?

I know ubuntu wont be as fast as windows but I am hoping by keeping both OS's on different physical disks I will make the setup more stable. Linux is lightening fat compared to windows 10 anyway so I am happy enough.

Sorry for the long post and your input and advice are greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: When you install Windows 10 or any supported Ubuntu distro to a bare drive nowadays, the default partition table type is GPT. You now have an MBR partition table.MBR is limited to three Primary partitions plus an Extended partition which contains many Logical partitions; GPT is all-primary, all the time. https://www.diskpart.com/gpt-mbr/mbr-vs-gpt-1004.html provides some detail on this.

Comment: Gparted shows its still GPT though? I definitely have more than 4 primaries